# Difference between send and trySend

Tags: android

What is the difference between `send` and `trySend` in callbaFlow?
I know that trySend returtn `ChannelResult` but I don't understand the next statement.

> This is **synchronous** variant of [send], which backs off in situations
> when `send` suspends or throws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`send` is a `suspend` function. So, it can only be invoked from a `suspend` function.

`trySend` is a regular function and it is synchronous. In other words, when you invoke `trySend`, you immediately get the result.

So, for example, with `trySend` you can do as follows:

```
if(trySend(element) == /*expected result*/) {
    //doSomething
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when say "synchronous"?